# AWS CloudFormation‎ Template : How to hide parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to add a Boolean parameter that defines if another parameter is shown or not.

For example:

```
{
   "Parameters":{
      "ShowParam":{
         "AllowedValues":[
            "true",
            "false"
         ],
         "Default":"false",
         "Type":"String"
      },
      "Param":{
         "Type":"String"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to show "Param" if "ShowParam" is set to true.

There is a way to achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean "hide parameter"? Do you mean that you don't want to use the parameter elsewhere in your template, or you don't want it to appear in the console? If the latter, you can't.

Comment: I don't want it to appear in the console. I want that the user won't be able to set a value to this parameter.

Comment: @kdgregory can't we use `NoEcho` in the parameter to hide sensitive information?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR - sure, but you can't set `NoEcho` based on another parameter (unless the docs are incorrect).  Parameters can only be used in `Resources` and `Outputs` definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "conditions" is not working for parameters/parameter groups. You can set the visibility/usability for resources and outputs. You can just create some parameter groups and set a comment as "optional". And for resources, if "param" is blank, you can set the resource value to "AWS::NoValue" to say "Cloudformation please ignore it!"

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to get this done:

1. put the information into a secret and reference directly in the template like this:

   ```
   {{resolve:secretsmanager:MySecret:SecretString:password:EXAMPLE1-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba987EXAMPLE}}
   ```

   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html)
2. if the value can be hard coded into the template, you could use mappings

   ```
   Mappings:
     Variables:
       VpcId:
         Value: vpc-xxxxxxx
   ```

   and then reference it like this:

   ```
   !FindInMap [Variables, VpcId, Value]
   ```